# Rentention policy in custom scope declaration of Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

In Dagger 2, when declare custom scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyScope {
}
```

I see many tutorials of Dagger2 use `RUNTIME` as the retention policy. I understand the differences betweeen `SROUCE`, `CLASS` and `RUNTIME`. But I don't understand why dagger custom scope in those tutorials all using `RUNTIME` as its retention policy.

I mean isn't it so that during compilation time the dependency graph is generated which means the scope should only be needed during compilation, then, why not use `CLASS` as the retention policy in custom scope of Dagger2 ? Anyone can explain to me?

Answer (score 2):

You're right. It doesn't matter with Dagger, but it might with other (runtime) dependency injection frameworks.

Dagger uses the `javax.inject` package which is also used by other DI frameworks and which also come with their own contract / documentation.

If you read up on [`Scope`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Scope.html) you'll see:

> A scope annotation [..] is annotated with `@Scope`, `@Retention(RUNTIME)`, and typically `@Documented`.

So it's really about sticking to that contract (and supporting other DI frameworks), not about how Dagger works internally.

Comment: What does `@Documented` actually mean in practice? If it means documentation what if I don't have documentation, what is the point of having the `@Documented`?